# Please how do I retrieve files saved in STDOUT after using the extract while downloading function?

Tags: files, tar, wget, stdout

I used the below function to download a large tar.gz file and extract it simultaneously. The files are now saved in STDOUT. Please how do I move them to a different file directory?

```
wget -q -O - target URL | tar -zxvf -
```

Comment: Please don't post images of your output. Text is much easier to parse and search within. Your files are saved in `server/data-seed/geth/chaindata`. You can use `mv` to place them wherever you need them to ultimately reside.

Comment: What do you mean by "The files are now saved in STDOUT"? The contents of the archive have been written to the current directory of the tar command.

Comment: @doneal24 Image removed. When I use the mv function, I get the following error: 

mv: cannot stat 'server/data-seed/geth/chaindata': No such file or directory

Comment: @Hauke Laging how to I access the current directory and move the files?

Comment: you mean like `mkdir -p somedir && wget ... | tar xCvf somedir -`

Comment: Edit your question with the `mv` command you are try to use, we cannot guess what you are doing. Use the `ls` command to see what files you got.

Comment: You removed the image but did not replace it with any useful information.  We now have the command you gave but no information on the output.

Answer (score 1):

They're not extracted on STDOUT¹, but the archive members are extracted as relative paths to the *current working directory*. For instance, if the archive contains members named `/foo`, `file1`, `dir`, and `dir/file2`, `dir/link -> file2` members, and the current working directory is `/home/sosa`, that would result in `/home/sosa/foo`², `/home/sosa/file1`, `/home/sosa/dir`, `/home/sosa/dir/file2`, `/home/sosa/dir/link` files being created.

If you wanted them to be extracted as relative paths to a different directory,  you'd use:

```
wget -q -O - URL | (cd some/other/directory && tar -zxvf -)
```

That is, `c`hange the current working `d`irectory of the process that will execute `tar` before it executes `tar` for `tar` to extract archive members relative to there.

With some `tar` implementations, you can also use the `-C` option for that:

```
wget -q -O - URL | tar -C some/other/directory -zxvf -
```

If you have already extracted the archive in the current working directory but  want the files to be moved elsewhere, then you need to identify which of the files in the current directory where extracted from the archive and which were already there.

If you have  extracted the archive in the last 10 minutes and no other file has been touched in the current directory in that interval, with `zsh`, you can do:

```
mv -- *(Dcm-10) /some/other/dir/
```

For the files with a *last change time* within the last 10 minutes to be moved to `/some/other/dir/`

Or with the GNU implementations of `find` and `mv`:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -cmin -10 -exec mv -vt /some/other/dir {} +
```

In our example above, that would move the `foo`, `file1` and `dir` files. The `dir/file2` and `dir/link` files strictly speaking don't move, they're still linked to that `dir` directory, but as that `dir` has moved, their new full path will be `/some/other/dir/dir/file2`, `/some/other/dir/dir/link`.

If you can't isolate a  time window that can allow you to identify the files, you'll need to download the archive again to retrieve the list of archive members, and extract the first path component of each. Assuming archive members don't contain newline characters, on a GNU system, you could do it as:

```
xargs -rd'\n' -a <(
  wget -qO- URL |
    tar -ztf - |
    LC_ALL=C sed -E 's@^((|\.|\.\.)/)*@@; s@/.*@@; /^(|\.|\.\.)$/d' |
    LC_ALL=C sort -u) mv -vt some/other/dir --
```

Where `wget` downloads the archive, `tar` with `-t` lists its content, `sed` removes leading `/`, `./`, `../` components¹ and all but the first path component (turning all of `foo/bar`, `/foo/bar` `/.././../foo/bar` into `foo`), `sort -u` removes duplicates, and `xargs` passes each line as individual arguments to `mv -t`.

Though, you'd likely want to save that list to a file first for inspection before doing the renaming to be on the safe side.

---

<sup>¹ for which you'd need the `O` option at least with GNU tar, but sending the contents of every file in the archive to stdout (for display if that command is issued in a terminal for instance) would likely not be what you want</sup>

<sup>² as most `tar` implementations strip leading `/` from archive members upon extraction as a safety measure. If there are members starting with `../`, some skip the member altogether, some strip the `../` components.</sup>

Comment: Your last example uses `wget` to download the archive but your explanation references `curl`. Might be confusing to a new user.

Comment: @doneal24, thanks. I had also incorrectly put curl in the code before. I'd fixed the code, but not the explanation. Fixed now.